# Cordova web app alert box replacement being nonmodal

Tags: cordova

In a Cordova/Phonegap web app, I have the ugly alert box replaced with the stylized HTML elements. It looks good.

The problem is now it becomes non-modal. If there are alert messages that's coming in asynchronously, our current implementation can have serious glitches (showing two content at once with two set of `OK` button on screen.) Obviously, this is not acceptable.

But only the original alert can be modal. What's the common solution to the problem?

Comment: Have you tried this [Cordova Dailogs Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs) ? You can add custom title and buttons to your alert box, this way it will not look ugly.

Comment: @KirankumarDafda Does this solves the modality (blocking) issue? If so wow how does it do so..

Comment: Oh I see it's calling the native ones.

Comment: Yes it is, So you can set the dialog box with require front end and calling respective function onclick of cancel or ok buttons